# How to load external resource files in Spark application?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hello I am trying to use some resource file which is a csv file, which I load in the spark application when I run it  using

```
   val resSource: BufferedSource = Source.fromResource("res.csv")
```

This work when I am using IDE and the csv is in resource folder.

But when I am trying to use ***assembly*** to create a fat JAR, This this code throws null pointer exception.

What is the best way to read external files when the JAR is deployed using spark-submit ?

I tried already answered solutions like **getClass.getResources** etc , these solutions dont work.
Can someone help me how to do it ?  I want to know how to use the
**--files** options and how to access it in the application ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ spark-shell --files data.txt


scala> import java.io.File
import java.io.File

scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles

scala> val rootDir = new File(SparkFiles.getRootDirectory())
rootDir: java.io.File = /private/var/folders/lr/shv51xn15zqdtzb67c7f4ydc0000gn/T/spark-ce4fd20e-ebd2-4c05-b6a7-39c338332dd3/userFiles-3c78071d-75bb-47e1-a3e0-0be2b83c1600

scala> rootDir.listFiles.foreach(x => println(x.getName))
data.txt

scala> val dataFile = SparkFiles.get("data.txt")
dataFile: String = /private/var/folders/lr/shv51xn15zqdtzb67c7f4ydc0000gn/T/spark-ce4fd20e-ebd2-4c05-b6a7-39c338332dd3/userFiles-3c78071d-75bb-47e1-a3e0-0be2b83c1600/data.txt

scala> spark.read.text(dataFile).show()
+---------------+
|          value|
+---------------+
|'$1,200.00',abc|
|'$1,201.00',und|
|'$1,202.00',jsn|
|'$1,203.00',yhs|
|'$1,204.00',rfs|
|'$1,205.00',jsn|
|'$1,202.00',han|
+---------------+
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$

Comment: Hi @Mansoor , The get returns a string , maybe the path of file... like this :

/tmp/spark-cf3f19ad-c2f3-4465-bf82-abc0913efddf/userFiles-d395b826-3f49-4325-95ac-2a7024993ea8/res.csv

How to get the content of the file ?

I tried to read, got FileNotFoundException

Comment: @Harold you should be able read the file through java.io.File or Scala Source on the absolute file path